# what could be triggering this error in my code "Expected type 'str', got 'tuple[int, int]' instead

Tags: python, class, oop, tuples, superclass

i have been searching to find out what the cause might be but to no avail. this is my main.py code below

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import time
from paddle import Paddle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.tracer(0)

l_paddle = Paddle((-200, 0))
r_paddle = Paddle((350, 0))



screen.listen()
screen.onkey(r_paddle.go_up, "Up")
screen.onkey(r_paddle.go_down, "Down")
screen.onkey(l_paddle.go_up, "w")
screen.onkey(l_paddle.go_down, "s")

game_is_on = True

while game_is_on:
    screen.update()
screen.exitonclick()
```

and the corresponding class

```
from turtle import Turtle


class Paddle(Turtle):
    def __int__(self, position):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("white")
        self.shapesize(stretch_len=1.0, stretch_wid=5.0)
        self.penup()
        self.goto(position)

    def go_up(self):
        new_y = self.ycor() + 20
        self.goto(self.xcor(), new_y)

    def go_down(self):
        new_y = self.ycor() - 20
        self.goto(self.xcor(), new_y)
```

i even checked to see if a similar issue has been solved here but couldn't see.

Comment: Please post the full traceback. We don't know where the error comes from otherwise.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but `def __int__(self, position):` should be `__init__` - its not being called when object is created.

Comment: the full error i get is this:

Comment: C:\Users\FSTC\PycharmProjects\pingpong\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/FSTC/PycharmProjects/pingpong/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FSTC\PycharmProjects\pingpong\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    l_paddle = Paddle((-200, 0))
  File "C:\Users\FSTC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 3815, in __init__
    RawTurtle.__init__(self, Turtle._screen,
  File "C:\Users\FSTC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 2546, in __init__
    self.turtle = _TurtleImage(screen, shape)

Comment: In future please do not put trackbacks in a comment.  They are impossible to read that way. Instead, [edit] your question and add them, formatted as code so that they appear in the readable way they were presented to you, not scrunched up in a ball. Even though you may not yet know how to read them, you are going to have to learn. Readability counts.

Answer (score 0):

check one of this solution
1)Try Paddle(-200, 0) insted of Paddle((-200, 0))
maybe because you are using two brackets it is getting confused.
2) I think you have misspelled the word "*init*" to "*int*".
3)Try r_paddle.go_up() since it is function. You seem to not have put "()" while calling the function.

Comment: i did all the above suggestions but still the error still lingers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue as you. That's because the **init**() function in Paddle class was written as **int**(). Once correct the init function, the issue would be fixed.